# Differential equations $2y' + 5y = 4$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The only method I know is separation of variables and I am instructed to use it on this as well.

$$2y' + 5y = 4$$

No clue how to proceed without an x or whatever term.

$$2\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = 4$$

$$2dy + 5ydx = 4dx$$

$$2dy  = (4 - 5y)dx$$

Can I implicitly integrate a y with dx? It isn't in my book. Regardless of that it gives the wrong answer anyways.

Comment: You cannot do that. Just divide through by $4 - 5y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide to get:
$$\int\frac{2}{4-5y} dy = \int dx =x+C$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: So what was the goal here? I don't follow the logic.

Comment: @PaulthePirate - you would get a function $x = f(y)$ that you can then invert to get $y = f(x)$ which is the solution you want to get to.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take it from
$$2dy  = (4 - 5y)dx$$
so
$$2\int\frac{dy}{4-5y}=-\frac{2}{5}\log(|4-5y|)=\int dx=x+C$$
hence $$y=\lambda e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+\frac{4}{5}$$

Answer (score 4):

Separation of variables can readily be applied here. You've found that

$$2\,dy = (4 - 5y) \,dx$$

Divide by $(4 - 5y)$ to "separate" the variables (all terms with respect to $y$ on the left, only $dx$ left on the right):

$$\frac 2{4 - 5y}\,dy = \,dx$$

Integrate each side of the equation:

$$\int \frac 2{4-5y}\,dy \;= \int \,dx$$

No doubt you can take it from here.